# Yii2 model error disappears in the view, why?

Tags: yii2

I have a view, which is including a form. If an attribute of the model is empty in the DB I see the form so I can immediately upload a file, which at the same time updates the attribute in the DB, so next time I see the data what I want according to what I've uploaded.

This is my controller:

```
public function actionView($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    ...
    if ($model->load($_POST)) {
        $this->actionUpload($id);
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}


public function actionUpload($id) {
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->upload()) {
        return $this->redirect(Url::previous());
    } else {
        # ***
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

*** If validation fails, at this point I can see the error, but in the view not any more, because it's empty. How can it be? It should be there, shouldn't it? Somewhere I'm doing a mistake but I have no clue how.

My View:

```
if ($model->attr) {
    echo $model->attr;
} else {
    echo $this->render('_upload', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

_upload:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'uploadedFiles[]')->fileInput([...
echo $form->errorSummary($model);

(submitButton)
```

Can you please tell me at which point my error can be disappearing?

Comment: What does `model->upload()` do?

Comment: `upload()` is validating and saving uploaded files.

Comment: can you put the code of that function?

Answer (score 1):

Merge both controller actions into one action. From first action you are calling the second action which does **redirect on success** - so it would never return back to first action.

Comment: I have only problem with the `else`. There is no redirect, only `render`, so I think it should be there. In the `else` it's there, only in the rendered view not.

Comment: You mean `else` in view? No, you have problem in Controller. On successful redirect you will loose all request data from previous request, so the view cannot work properly. You may want to debug it, if you don't see it.

Comment: If upload succeeds I have no problem with redirecting, because it means there weren't any errors ==> there is nothing to show. My problem is if upload doesn't succeed ==> I have an error what I want to show of course, and I think simply in a `render` (so no redirect) should the error be accessible in the rendered view.